# List of objects inside a HashMap issue

Tags: java, list, hashmap, concurrenthashmap, inverted-index

I am building an inverted index file for my search engine. I have written the class however, when I try to test it, the program gets stuck in this part:

```
for (final HashObject value: list) {

   if(url.equals(value.getUrl()))
       value.setFrequency();

   if(!url.equals(value.getUrl())){       
       list.add(new HashObject(title, term, url, 1, 1));           
   }
}
```

Whenever I delete the block of code placed above, the whole search engine keeps crawling correctly. It seems that it gets stuck as the program takes no further actions...
You can see the whole code here:

```
/*
 * Classname: InvertedFile
 * Version: 1.1
 * Date: 15/04/2014
 * Copyright by Mateusz Michalski

 * Description: This class implements an inverted builder for storing results of crawling.
 */

package searchengine;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class InvertedFile
{
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<HashObject>> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public static int docCollection = 0;

    SearchEngine searchEngine = new SearchEngine();

    public void insertValues(String title, String term, String url)
    {
        if (!myMap.containsKey(term)){
            List<HashObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(new HashObject(title, term, url, 1, 1));
            myMap.put(term, list);
        }

        if(myMap.containsKey(term)){            
            List<HashObject> list = myMap.get(term);

            for (final HashObject value: list) {          
                 if(url.equals(value.getUrl()))
                     value.setFrequency();

                if(!url.equals(value.getUrl())){          
                    list.add(new HashObject(title, term, url, 1, 1));

                //for (HashObject val: itemList)
                    //val.setDoc();
                }
            }              
            myMap.put(term, list);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no clue why it gets stuck in that for loop. I might be too tired already and hopefully not seeing a minor mistakes... Can anyone give me their opinions on this code?

Comment: Do you expect this to work concurrently?

Comment: Not at the moment, no.

Comment: I think this is because you are structurally modifying the `list` when it is being iterated. If you use a classic iterator, the recommended way is to add/remove via the `add` and `remove` methods of the `Iterator`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). I think this holds true for the enhanced for loop as well, but I am not (yet) able to find documentation.

Comment: The Java [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) says that `iterator.remove` is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress. I think it holds good for `add` as well.

Comment: Well spotted, thank you Nivas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problematic loop is intended to do as it seems that you are checking for the  `url` passed in as a parameter to exist in the `HashObject` of the current iteration through the list, and if not found in there insert a new `HashObject` in the list which has its `url` value as that of the passed in `url`. If none of the existing `HashObject`s have the same value as the passed in `url`, then you will be insterting multiple `HashObject`s in the list with the same value for `title`, `term`, `url` etc.

If this is indeed what you need then use a `ListIterator` for adding while iterating through the list. You can read more about the [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28E%29) method of `ListIterator`.

```
ListIterator listIter = list.listIterator();
while (listIter.hasNext()) { 
    HashObject value = listIter.next();       
    if(url.equals(value.getUrl())){
        value.setFrequency();
    }

    if(!url.equals(value.getUrl())){          
        listIter.add(new HashObject(title, term, url, 1, 1));
    }
}
```

But maybe on discovering that none of your `HashObject`s in the list have the passed in url, you want to insert a new `HashObject` with that url only once. In that case the code above will have to change.